# Java Loop control (while)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
    int levelP1;
    int levelP2;
    do {
        p1.startTurn(p1, d1);
        p2.startTurn(p2, d1);
        levelP1 = p1.getLevel();
        levelP2 = p2.getLevel();
    } while (levelP1 <= 10 || levelP2 <= 10);
    if (levelP1 >= 10) {
        System.out.println(p1.getName() + " hit LvL " + levelP1 + " and WON the game !");
    } else if (levelP2 >= 10) {
        System.out.println(p2.getName() + " hit LvL " + levelP2 + " and WON the game !");
    }
```

I have this pieace of code which is not doing what it is intended... 
the "startTurn()" method might or might not level up the player, depending of what happens inside of it...
I want it to exit the loop when either player hits level 10 or above... Cannot figured out how. please help

Comment: your if condition should be inside `while` with `break` statement

Comment: If you want it to exit the loop when *either* player hits level 10 *or above*, that means when `levelP1 >= 10 || levelP2 >= 10`, and since loop condition is the opposite, that means `while (levelP1 < 10 && levelP2 < 10);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want it to exit the loop when either player hits level 10 or above.

Use `&&` instead of  `||` :

```
while (levelP1 < 10 && levelP2 < 10);
```

In this way, when one of these two conditions is false, you exit.

Comment: Also drop `=`. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958114/java-loop-control-while#comment74947168_43958114).

Comment: But if i use &&, 
won't that make me exit the loop when BOTH conditions are false ? which is not what i want

Comment: No. The while condition is true while both conditions are true. You want exit when `levelP1 >=10 OR levelP2 >=10`. It means that you want to go on while `levelP1 <10 AND levelP2 <10`

Comment: You can also use `while (!(levelP1 >= 10 || levelP2 >= 10));` if it helps you to understand. It is an equivalent  that uses the negation.